# jQuery track progress of an image load

Tags: javascript, jquery, gif

I've got some functionality on my site where I initially show a static image, then when clicked I show a loading image until an mage variable has been loaded with a gif at which time I show the gif.

It works nicely as can be seen here
http://www.lazygamer.net/xbox-360/has-watchdogs-been-downgraded-since-e3-2012/

However what I'd like to do is update a label with the progress of the loading. I tried the following in my click event to change the image

```
var img = new Image();
var $el = jQuery(this);
img.onprogress = function(e) {
  if (e.lengthComputable)
    $mydiv.html(e.loaded / e.total * 100);
}
img.src= 'http://myfile.com/test.gif';
```

but the onprogress simply doesn't fire ever.

I don't get any errors in the console either, it's just ignored?

Comment: What is `img` in your example code? And where does `e` come from? If you meant `$el.onprogress`, then a simple fix would be to use `$el.get(0).onprogress` instead, and to make `e` the first argument to the function. Perhaps you can use `$el.on("progress", function...` too.

Comment: This article might help you too, it describes the process I went through reading your code snippet: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Sorry trying to use a sub secton of the code.. img is a new Image and e was in the function declaration

Comment: I've not been able to find any documentation which says that onprogress should work, and in the source for your example page, the one use of onprogress I can see is commented out.

Comment: Yeah I commented it out since it wasn't working.. I was working from this example http://blogs.adobe.com/webplatform/2012/01/13/html5-image-progress-events/

Comment: Ah, I came across that when looking for docs. This seems to be the key line: "A proposed alternative approach, which would require additional progress events on the image element, could go like this..."  Perhaps there are no shipping browsers which support it yet?